# Correct type for children props in wrapper class?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lint

Im trying to create a wrapper class that simply returns children props

```
type Props {
  children: any;
}

const Wrapper: = ({ children }: Props) {
  //some logic

  return children;
}
```

Curios if it exist a more specific type than `any` for this purpose? If i try something like `ReactNode` or `JSX.Element` i can no longer pass multiple children. On the other hand by using a fragment, the linter complains because `children` may also be a single element.

```
const Wrapper: React.FC = ({ children }) =>  {
  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

Any thought appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`React.ReactNode` is the correct type of the `children` prop of React components. And React components must return a `JSX.Element`.

These are not the same type.

`children` may be a list, and react components *must* return a single node. So you just have to wrap `children` in a fragment to guarantee you always get a single `JSX.Element`.

```
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Wrapper = ({ children }: Props) => {
  //some logic

  return <>{children}</>;
}

// works
const test1 = <Wrapper>123</Wrapper>
const test2 = <Wrapper>
  <>foo</>
  <>bar</>
</Wrapper>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOABRzAGc4BeOAb1LjjQAtgAGwAmRAHYAuRMRgA6ZOhgA5CMKQBuUgF9yaCGKbwA6lBRgaUNnAAUHXgJHi4WqQwjMAlGwB8nbnAB6AKZcWkEIAHNgNH8iGABXKDE4AB5vDn4hUSQxLRSA700dUiC4AHdoAGsmUj0DeBgkQwBGKxSTMwtvZoAmAGZ8jvMkKG9a-UM4RsMetqGu-zTMCAh8sZ40gCMUKDXSQdNh0aA)

Answer (score 1):

Use React.PropsWithChildren

```
function Wrapper({
  prop1,
  children
}: React.PropsWithChildren<{ prop1: string }>) {
  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the children prop to a type that satisfies the return type of `React.FC`

```js
const Wrapper: React.FC = ({ children }) =>  {
  return children as React.ReactElement;
}
```